# How to load my map on my page

Tags: dictionary

How to show the pape on page.I have issues loading the map.  http://pinquest.eu/

Comment: Explain your question a bit more.  What map are you trying to load? What have you tried? What error messages are you getting?

Comment: I have already this map on my server but when i tried to move it to client server its not loading i changed the api as well..  http://pkfones.com/pinquest/

Comment: simply saying i want to install it on   http://pinquest.eu/ the map is currently here   http://pkfones.com/pinquest/.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a map with markers on your website with openlayers. It is described here: 
[map on website](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenLayers)